# Does using Angular 2 router make sense in Ionic 2 application?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, angular2-routing, ng-modules

We have made an attempt at moving our Angular 2 app (written by a friend of ours, thus we might not know all the details) into Ionic 2. However, we haven't managed to make it work yet, thus questions below.

1. Will Angular 2 router work in Ionic 2?
2. Does it make sense to use Angular 2 router in Ionic 2 apps or should we go straight to an alternative, like [DeepLinker](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/navigation/DeepLinker/)?

EDIT: I am not sure what the current state is, but I read [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/examples-for-ionic-2-with-angular-2-router/45186/6) that:

> «The Angular router is currently under heavy development and refactoring. As a result of this, Angular’s router is currently disabled within Ionic.»

3. Where in the code/metadata/build-script/`package.json` is the entry point that activates the router? We have the routing in the NgModule but it does not seem to be kicking into action when we access the app's main URL nor sub-URLs:

   ```
   @NgModule({
     declarations: [
       AppComponent,
       TestComponent,
       AgendasListComponent,
       TasksListComponent,
       SnackBarComponent,
       ConfirmationDialog,
       AgendaComponent,
       LoginComponent
     ],
     entryComponents: [
       ConfirmationDialog
     ],
     imports: [
       BrowserModule,
       HttpModule,
       MaterialModule.forRoot(),
       AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig, firebaseAuthConfig),
       RouterModule.forRoot([
       {
         path: '',
         redirectTo: 'agendas',
         pathMatch: 'full',
         canActivate:[ RouterGuardService ]
       },           
       {
         path: 'agendas',
         component: AgendasListComponent,
         canActivate:[ RouterGuardService ]           
       }
       ...
   ```

Comment: Ionic runs on angular 2 therefore the codebase will be compatible. If you have a specific problem with ionic please post a runnable code example demonstrating the problem

Comment: Thanks @codeninja. I understand it should work, but I have my doubts due to what it says [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/examples-for-ionic-2-with-angular-2-router/45186/6) about angular router being disabled in Ionic: `The Angular router is currently under heavy development and refactoring. As a result of this, Angular’s router is currently disabled within Ionic.` Not sure if it's still the case.

Comment: Not sure either, but looking at their documentation around navigation it seems that you navigate like you do in ios, by pushing views to the navigation stack. If this doesn't suit you can opt out of using ionic and just use cordova or similar

Comment: Why not use ionic 2's built in navigation ?

Comment: @gerdi if we could make it work with Angular 2 router that we are already using, that would be great. We will switch to an alternative if it makes more sense, but that's additional work.

Comment: Well i think you are going to spend more time getting it to work rather then just using the already built in navigation system, which is very complete and simple to use

Comment: @user1752532 I would disagree with the statement 'Ionic's navigation system is complete', especially in the context of web apps.  What about supporting Google Search indexing?  Ionic routing, even with deeplinking hooked up, fails miserably.  Sooner or later, if you want your site to be indexed properly, you will end up going with the Angular router.

Answer (score 14):

I'm sorry for the late suggestion. I've been there where you are too. And honestly, Ionic is a nightmare. It was good though, until...

The reason we use Ionic is to develop once, and deploy multiple times. web, mobile/tablet and possibly windows (linux?)...

But the mere thought, that the app we're building looks horrible on the web, like an enlarged mobile app. I gave it a try, thinking I'd adjust it a bit. But then, I would leave whole initial idea, having to maintain multiple code bases.

This, on the UI part. But then I found out with the arrival and development of Ng2, Ionic also chose to introduce NavController, in stead of waiting for the (reactive) Router... And that's where things got messy... So, besides having to worry about two code bases for the UI, I also had to rewrite it for the Router / NavController conflicts.

Meanwhile, my eye fell on [Minks Gechev's Angular Seed](https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed) and also successfully mixed the Ionic base with it.

After having had a silencing discussion on an Ionic Github Issue, in which more than 15 people shared my concerns about the NavController problem. In which an Ionic core developer tried to silence us, telling us "it will be solved soon", on which I asked to "define soon". He almost kicked me out.

Meanwhile, I just tingled with [Nathan's Angular Advanced Seed](https://github.com/NathanWalker/angular-seed-advanced). Nathan is working for Telerik, the driver behind the open source Nativescript (which is now a separate foundation itself)

At first, I was sceptical, because Telerik tends to overpromise. I've tried to shoot at it, but it really is faster and it is not-hybrid, it is native.

I myself do like flexbox. So, I'd search for a (web/windows) UI using it. Why not Onsen?

So, go to Nathan's seed and get Onsen in it. This is the frontend. Backend - Keycloak and vert.x

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using Angular 2 router the recommendation is to use NavController & Co: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/navigation/NavController/.

Ionic 2 also has support for [Deep Links into your application](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/navigation/DeepLinker/) as you have noted yourself. You can read the official blog post here: http://blog.ionic.io/deeplinking-in-ionic-apps/.

Here is a plugin for this https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugin-deeplinks which allows you to create custom URLs that will open your application to specific views if that is one of your requirements.